# PostgreSQL. exclusive permission to a function to modify a table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, permissions

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to give a function exclusive right to modify a table?
For example, is it possible for a trigger to know which function accessed a table with modification or insertion intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do that via users, by using a different user to run the function than for all other access.

One option would be a `NOLOGIN` role that owns the function. Now if that function is declared as `SECURITY DEFINER`, it will always run with in the context of its owner. Now if that owner is the only role with permission to modify the table, you have your solution.

Comment: Thank you, that is a solution. And very likely I will use that. How ever I remain curious if a trigger can know which function is accessing its table. This information should be obtainable in some way.

Comment: There is the `current_query` function, but that only shows the top-level query.You would have to write a trigger in C that examines the parse tree of the current query.